# /usr/local/bin/vim: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: bash, vim, neovim

Trying to learn more about the many mysteries of bash.

I have neovim installed. I have `nvim` aliased to `vim`. I have `nvim` configured to use my vim config.

Let's say I want to use the real `vim` command, though. `which vim` yields "/usr/local/bin/vim".

But calling `/usr/local/bin/vim` directly results in the error given in the title. Why is that? How can I run my `vim` command directly?

Comment: This is error usually happens when trying to run an executable unfit for the current system. Can you add the result of `file /usr/local/bin/vim` and `uname -a` so we could understand better the executable format and your environment?

Comment: `file` gives: "/usr/local/bin/vim: data". `uname -a` yields: "Darwin iMac5K.local 18.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.5.0: Mon Mar 11 20:40:32 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.251.3~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/vim` is linked to "../Cellar/vim/8.1.1000/bin/vim". That must be homebrew's doing.

Comment: If I go to Cellar/vim/8.1.1000/bin/ and run `vim` it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the result of the `file` command it seems that the file in `/usr/local/bin/vim` is somehow broken (the system doesn't recognize it as an elf file).

The `file` command should identify any executable file with the file format (and other types of files). When this command returns output of `data` it means that it couldn't identify the file at all.

---

Since you found the vim executable in `Cellar/vim/8.1.1000/bin/vim`, you can use this file instead of file which is in `/usr/local/bin/vim`, or you can create the link by yourself, that should fix this error.

If you would create the link with absolute path instead of relative path, it should work.

Comment: Making the link absolute did not help. Here's another odd thing. If I go into `/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.1.1000/bin` directory and run `vim` it works. But, trying to run the command with the full path: `/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.1.1000/bin/vim` gives me the "Exec format error" again.

Comment: Ah, disregard last. `./vim` from that directory gives me the error.

Comment: I'm looking at timestamp of that file and it changed a couple of hours ago. I think it got corrupted somehow. I was using a script with vim in a weird way. Hmm.

Comment: OK, reinstalling vim with brew fixed things up. Thanks for the help tracking this down!